# Using multiple independant gulpfiles to build different bundles

Tags: javascript, symfony, bundle, gulp

here's the scenacrio.

Let's say I habe a main app with different sub-apps inside (or bundles in symfony world). Each app has own scripts and styles, independent from the other. These sub apps should as less coupled as possible because they're more coming or can be removed anytime.

App-Dir

- style (main-app)
- scripts (main-app)
- subapps

  - app1

    - style
    - script
    - gulpfile.js
  - app2

    - style
    - script
    - gulpfile.js
- dist (target

  - maincss.css (mainapp)
  - mainjs.js (mainapp)
  - subapp1

    - style.css (app1 style)
    - script.js (app1 js)
      .....
- gulpfiles.js

Each gulpfile should be self concerned because they can have different build requirements (less or plain, minify or not, ....)

I'm trying to implement a sceanrio where the main gulpfile calls all subapp gulpfiles with a target directory. Each sub-gulpfile generates it's files and copies it to the target directory.

Can you show me a nice way to accomplish this?

I found chug (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-chug) but when I read along I found a discussion that this is not the right way.

I couldn't find an approach with require which is fullfills my black-box approch.

thx

Comment: downvoted because you did't show us what you tried and why you are not satisfied with it. Will upvote if you can edit

Comment: Even though I did attempt to answer your question, I do agree with @Apolo. Questions are better received when you show examples of your own attempts to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this or at least it will point you in the right direction:

#### main gulpfile.js

```
require('./gulp');
require('./app1/gulp');
require('./app2/gulp');
```

### your gulp folder(s) would look like this

- gulp

  - tasks

    - task1.js
    - task2.js
  - index.js

### index.js would then require your tasks which can be specific to each app

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var onlyScripts = function(name) {
                     return /(\.(js)$)/i.test(path.extname(name));
                  };

var tasks = fs.readdirSync('./gulp/tasks/').filter(onlyScripts);

tasks.forEach(function(task) {
  require('./tasks/' + task);
});
```

### an example of as task inside the task folder

```
var gulp         = require('gulp');
var sass         = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync  = require('browser-sync');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('styles', function () {

  return gulp.src([src-of-this-app])
    .pipe(sass({
      sourceComments: 'map',
      sourceMap: 'sass',
      outputStyle: 'nested'
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer("last 2 versions", "> 1%", "ie 8"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest([dest-of-this-app]))
    .pipe(gulpif(browserSync.active, browserSync.reload({ stream: true })));

});
```

#### this way you can separate your task into different folders for each app